# Spring, NotReadablePropertyException and Glassfish version

Tags: java, spring-mvc, glassfish

I am working on a web-application that uses Spring MVC.

It has been working fine on Glassfish 3.0.1, but when migrating to Glassfish 3.1, it started acting strange. Some pages are only partially showing, or showing nothing at all, and in the log, a lot of messages of this type:

```
    [#|2012-08-30T11:50:17.582+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=69;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|StandardWrapperValve[SpringServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet SpringServlet threw exception
    org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'something' of bean class [com.something.Something]: Bean property 'something' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:576)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:719)
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:226)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag.writeTagContent(TextareaTag.java:95)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
```

The error message isn't incorrect, because the property in question does not have a setter-method (gets its value through the constructor). But like I said, this has not been a problem when using Glassfish 3.0.1, only when using it on the new server with Glassfish 3.1.

Does anyone know if there is something in the Glassfish version that might cause this? Or is it some kind of configuration that is missing on the new server?

Some code:

Controller:

```
@ModelAttribute
public SomethingContainer retriveSomethingContainer(@PathVariable final long id {
    return somethingContainerDao.retrieveSomethingContainer(id);       
}

@InitBinder("somethingContainer")
public void initBinderForSomething(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAllowedFields(new String[] {
        "something.title",
        "something.description",
    });
}
```

SomethingContainer:

```
@Embedded
private final Something something = new Something();

public Something getSomething() {
    return something;
}
//no setter

public String getDescription() {
    return something.getDescription();
}
```

Update:

Restarting Glassfish actually removes the problem - temporarily. I suspect that it might have something to do with the loading of the custom binders, we had some problems with out of memory errors, which I thought had something to do with it, but that has been fixed without fixing this problem.

Update 2:

On the 3.0.1 server, the one of the jvm arguments was -client. On the 3.1-server, it was -server. We changed it to -client, and this made the frequency of the error go down a lot, it was happening every other day with -server, took 2 weeks for it to happen with -client.

Update 3:

Some information about the servers (more can be added if requested..)

Server1 (the working one):

```
Windows Server 2003
Java jdk 6 build 35
Glassfish 3.0.1 build 22
-xmx 1024m
```

Server2 (the one with problems):

```
Windows Server 2008 64-bit
Java jdk 6 build 31
Glassfish 3.1 build 43
-xmx 1088m
-xms 1088m
```

We are using Spring version 3.1.0.

Update 4:

I recreated the error by renaming a field in a jsp to something that does not exist in the modelattribute.

But, more importantly, I noticed something: The fields where the system can't find the getters are often fields of superclasses of the ones that are referenced in the modelattribute. To continue my example, the SomthingContainer is really like this:

```
public class SuperSomethingContainer {
    [...]
    private Something something;
    public Something getSomething() {
        return something;
    }
}

public class SomethingContainer extends SuperSomethingContainer {
    [...]
}
```

The reference in the controller stays as is, so it's referencing a field that is in the superclass of the object in question.

Update 5:

I tried connecting to the production server with a debugger after the error occured. I put a breakpoint on the return statement of a controller-method returning the object with the error, and tried to see if I could access the field with problems at the time. And that I could, so the problem must lie within Spring MVC/the generated jsp-classes.

(Also, the field in error was of the type "someobject.something[0].somethingelse[0]", but when the somethingelse-list was empty, there was no error! To me, this implies that it somehow can't find the get-method of a list(?))

Update 6:

It seems that the problem has to do with the generation of Java-classes from the jsps. We have not used precompile jsps when deploying, so they are compiled when first used. The problem occurs the first time a page is visited, and the jsp compiled. I also noticed that once the problem has occured, jsps that are compiled after will all give errors. I've kept a few of the problem generated java files, and upon the next restart I will compare them to the working ones. Getting closer :)

Update 7:

Compared the compiled jsp java files that resulted in an error with ones that did not, and there was no difference. So that kinda leaves that out.

So, I now know that the Java object leaving the controller is fine (checked with debugger),  and the java class generated from the jsp is fine. So it must be something in between, now I need to find out what...

Update 8:

Another round of debugging, and narrowed the problem down some more. It turns out that spring does some caching of the properties belonging to the various classes. In org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl, method getPropertyValue, there is the following:

```
private Object getPropertyValue(PropertyTokenHolder tokens) throws BeansException {
    String propertyName = tokens.canonicalName;
    String actualName = tokens.actualName;
    PropertyDescriptor pd = getCachedIntrospectionResults().getPropertyDescriptor(actualName);
    if (pd == null || pd.getReadMethod() == null) {
        throw new NotReadablePropertyException(getRootClass(), this.nestedPath + propertyName);
    }
```

The problem is that the cachedIntrospectionResults does not contain the property in question, it contains every other property of the class though. Will need to dig some more to try to find out why it is missing, if it's missing from the start or if it gets lost somewhere along the line.

Also, I've noticed that the missing properties are those that do not have setters, only getters. And, it seems to be context aware, as indicated by the stacktrace. So not finding a property when visiting one page does not mean that its not available when visiting another.

Update 9:

Another day, more debugging. Actually found some good stuff. The getCachedIntrospectionResults() call in the previous code block wounded up calling CachedIntrospectionResults#forClass(theClassInQuestion). This returned a CachedIntrospectionResults object, containing far from all of the properties expected (11 of 21). Going into the forClass-method, I found:

```
static CachedIntrospectionResults forClass(Class beanClass) throws BeansException {
    CachedIntrospectionResults results;
    Object value = classCache.get(beanClass);
    if (value instanceof Reference) {
        Reference ref = (Reference) value;
        results = (CachedIntrospectionResults) ref.get();
    }
    else {
        results = (CachedIntrospectionResults) value;
    }
    if (results == null) {
    //build the CachedIntrospectionResults, store it in classCache and return it.
```

It turned out that the CachedIntrospectionResults returned was found by classCache.get(beanClass). So what was stored in the classCache was corrupted/did not contain all that it should. I put a breakpoint on the classCache.get(beanClass)-line, and tried running this through the debugger:

> classCache.put(beanClass, null);

When allowing the method to finish, and rebuild the CachedIntrospectionResults, things started working again. So, what is being stored in the classCache is out of sync with what would and should be created if it was allowed to rebuild it. Whether this is due to something going wrong the first time it is built, or if the classCache is corrupted somewhere along the line I do not currently know.

I'm starting to suspect that this has something to do with classloaders, as I've previously experienced problems due to changes in the way the classloader works when updating Glassfish..

Comment: I'm thinking about Spring not finding getters because getters return some type that's not available at runtime. How? Classloaders. Maybe your project is compiled against all libraries, but them, somehow because of new configuration, classes for that getters are not available. Maybe they where available at root server classloader and now they're somewhere else (or nowhere). What type is it? JRE/Glassfish/3d library/your project?

Comment: I was also suspecting that it had something to do with classloaders, after checking a heap dump. It looks like each page is loaded by a separate org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader (there are 100s of these in the heap, each containing the jsps and tags to create one page. Also, there are a lot of org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoaderJava5). But I still find it strange that this should happen over time (it works fine for a period of time before it starts throwing exceptions), this must mean that the classloaders become corrupted somehow?

Comment: Very strange that time dependance...

Comment: Are you using hibernate/JPA/some other ORM?

Comment: We are using Hibernate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a colleague of mine investigate the error, and he was able to recreate it in a unit test. This was done by invoking the method that builds CachedIntroSpectionResults for a class, while at the same time stressing the jvm by adding strings to the memory, with very low memory settings. This approach made it fail 20/30000 times.

As to the cause of it, I only got an oral explanation, so I don't have all the details, but it was something like this: Java has its own introspection-results, and these are wrapped by Spring. The problem is that the java-results utilize soft references, which make them prone to garbage collections. So, when Spring was building its wrappers around these soft references at the exact same time that the garbage collector ran, it actually cleared some of the basis of what Spring was using, leading to properties being "lost".

The solution seems to be upgrading from Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE to Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE. Here, there are some changes, and Spring no longer wraps soft references when determining the properties of a class (soft reference are used in rare, special cases, instead of all the time). After upgrading the version of Spring, the error has not been reproducable through the unit test, it remains to see if this is the case through in practice use.

Update: It's been a few weeks, an no sign of the error. So updating Spring version worked :)

Answer (score 2):

There may be more than one possible reason. I am not sure about the actual but I can give you the way to find out the problem

**Step 1:** on ***server 2*** machine deploy application on ***Glassfish 3.0.1 build 22*** , now if it works fine on the server 2 machine that it means there might be problem with the libraries of Glass fish, following can be reason for this problem

1. Any library that is missing in the ***Glassfish 3.1 build 43*** that is in ***Glassfish 3.0.1 build 22***. you can solve by copying all libraries from working Glassfish server to new server.
2. My be the libraries of Glassfish is conflicting with spring version. [*Similliar kind of problem I have faced on tomcat and when i replaced my spring libraires from 3.0.1 to 3.0.3 it worked for me]* , so replace your spring libraries with latest one.

**Step 2:**  and if the result of step1 is that application is not running on server 2 machin on Glassfish 3.0.1 build 22 there may be following reason

1. if any libraries that you have pasted on ***java lib*** either not included in this server machine or having different versions.
2. Any folders that are set on ***classpath*** or using any ***environment variables*** on server 1, either does not exist on server 2  or don't have the jars or having jars with diff versions

Comment: I do not have full control of the servers, and since this is in a production environment, they were reluctant to changing the glassfish version. Of course, if all else fails i'm going to force them to, but I would like to explore other possibilities and keep this as a last resort. Spring is at version 3.1.0.RELEASE, which is the last one as far as I know. I don't think glassfish keep the libraries, they are packaged in the .war-file that is deployed. But I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've actually found a candidate for the cause of this.

After getting the error on one of the test-servers after a very short duration and little use, we did some additional checks on the cause. It turned out that the test-server had just half the available memory, which turned us into looking at it a bit more thoroughly. It turned out that it hadn't used up all its memory, but when using JConsole to investigate the memory usage of the different part of the new generation space on the heap, it turned out that one of the surivior spaces was packed full. I'm guessing that this made parts of it overflow, leading to the overflowed parts to be GC-ed or unreachable by not being where it was supposed to.

We have yet to verify that this is in fact the problem in the production environment as well, but once the error turns up again we will check, and if it is the case we will change some memory settings to allow more space for survival areas of the new generation heap. (-XX:SurvivorRatio=6 or something like that).

So it seems that larger Spring MVC applications has a need for a large survivor space, specially in newer versions of Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there had been an issue with the new introduced `ExtendedBeanInfo` class in Spring 3.1.0, which had been fixed in Spring 3.1.1 - see (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8347).