# How to tell if one of the heap-generations is full?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

We are experiencing some problems in our production environment, where we get an InvalidPropertyException from one of the compiled jsps (which one differs from time to time) after a bit of time. I have a suspicion that this is caused by something "disappearing" from the heap. Further, I suspect that this is due to one of the generations of the heap becoming full, so some objects "spill" into a different generation where it is eventually GC-ed.

What I am wondering is: Is it possible to automatically monitor the heap, and alert when one of the generations are full and there is a posibility for such a spill? This could either be programatically or through some configuration.. We have tried using JConsole, but only after the error has started occuring, and then everything looks OK, but what I would really like is to know what it looks like at the exact time when the error occurs (or actually a few minutes before), without having to manually monitor.

I have posted a more general question for this problem, which has some more details: [Spring, NotReadablePropertyException and Glassfish version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194503/spring-notreadablepropertyexception-and-glassfish-version)

Comment: How on Earth can something disappear from the heap? It's either garbage or isn't.

Comment: Just an aside, heap generations really don't work like that. Whether something is garbage collectable is based on whether it is still referencable from a running thread. The generations just allow the garbage collector to easily collect short lived objects. JVM bugs aside, which generation the object is in has no impact on whether it is collectable, just how often it will be checked and how.

Comment: Well, it appearantly does disappear. I can't really see any other cause for a property suddenly disappearing from an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to say that it's impossible that your problem is heap-related, but if it was it would indicate a serious and very major bug in the memory subsystem and garbage collector in the JVM. While of course not impossible, it's highly, highly unlikely nonetheless as it would surely have been discovered by multiple other people and I have not heard anyone else reporting anything similar.

Basically, objects are never GC:ed while there is still at least one live reference to the object.  Moving between generations in the heap has nothing to do with it, that is just background work done by the GC to optimize memory handling. In fact, not all JVM:s even have generations.

If you have objects that "disappear", it's either because you're using `WeakReference` or `SoftReference` or because you simply de-reference the object in your code, making it eligible for reclamation.

If you post more details on your actual exception (stacktraces etc) and relevant code, perhaps someone here can help you find the problem.

Comment: The reason that I think it is somehow memory related is that the exception being thrown (org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException) had previously been thrown in conjunction with OutOfMemoryError when we used Glassfish 3.0.1. Now, we use glassfish 3.1.1, and it appears even when there is no outofmemoryerror. Other things that indicates that this is somehow a memory issue is the temporal factor, it works fine for a while until the exception is thrown (and then the exception is thrown every time), and it starts working again upon a restart of glassfish.

Comment: I have already posted a question related to the error I'm getting, this is kind of a follow-up on a lead.. I'll edit my question and add a link to the other question..

Comment: @Tobb well, it's good to follow up, but I would consider this lead dead for now. Objects simply don't disappear from the heap and there is no provision or mechanism in Java that will remove legitimate objects just because you are low on memory, it's simply not how the JVM works. It will throw OOM exceptions, sure, and crash but it will never silently just remove existing objects and keep running.

Comment: I see, one thing ruled out then :)

Answer (score 0):

Comments aside, if you really do want to see what is going on with the different generations, turn on Verbose GC logging. Just add `-verbose:gc` and `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` to your java command. This will result in a GC log that includes lines like:

```
94.198: [Full GC (System) 94.198: [Tenured: 788K->759K(4096K), 0.0428238 secs] 883K->759K(5056K), [Perm : 2095K->2095K(12288K)], 0.0429641 secs]
```

This tells you how much space is used by each generation before and after garbage collection.

[This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) also has a lot or info on this topic, as does [this blog](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.co.nz/2007/09/more-human-friendly-java-gc-timestamps.html) that I grabbed the above log example from.